# functions return add to variable

Tags: javascript

I have an array of prices for items

```
var st = [0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To Then figure out how much money the player gets it runs this function

```
function buy(a) {
money += st[return a;]
}
```

This should make

```
function buy(a) {
money += st[1]
}
```

The button pressed to run buy() with look like this

```
<button onclick='buy(1)'>Sell</button>
```

When they press this button it should return 1 and therefore add $1 to the players account but I am getting and error

```
Unexpected keyword 'return'
```

If you need any more information I would be happy to supply it

[fidde](https://jsfiddle.net/0zzv5yc6/) if you need it

Comment: That's just completely invalid JavaScript syntax. What do you expect `buy` to do?

Comment: `a` is holding value as `1`, what do you expect with `return 1` ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess it simply adds appropriate price from an array of prices to `money` variable, so should be as simple as `money += st[a]`

Comment: With the return you will get money += st[1]

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I had no clue how to do this so I just thought this might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message tells you, `return` has no place where you've put it. You've put a *statement* (`return a;`) inside a property accessor (`st[...]`). That just isn't valid.

From the way you're using `buy`, you don't want `return` at all:

```
function buy(a) {
    money += st[a];
}
```

But if you did want it to return a value, you'd use `return` separately. For instance, if you wanted to return the updated value of `money`:

```
function buy(a) {
    money += st[a];
    return money;
}
```

*(Technically, `return money += st[a];` would also return the updated value of `money`, but I'm showing them separately for emphasis and clarity.)*

Or if you wanted to return `a` for some reason:

```
function buy(a) {
    money += st[a];
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have syntax errors

```
function buy(a) {
return money += st[a];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is wrong, you **cannot** use return in index of Array.

```
function buy(a) {
money += st[a];
return money;
}
```

Or you can use :

```
function buy(a) {
return (money += st[a]);
}
```

**Assuming that your money variable is already defined**...